# List index is out of range, how do I fix that?

Tags: python

I am coding a game of blackjacks.

The output says that my list index is out of range, why is that?

my code:

```
playercard1 = randint (cards[0],cards[12])
if cards[playercard1] == 10 or cards[playercard1] == 11 or cards[playercard1] == 12:
    print ("Your card has a point value of ten.")
    playerpoints = playerpoints + 10
```

Comment: Well, what is `len(cards)`? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Did you want `random.choice(cards)` to "pick a random card"?

Comment: What does `cards` contain?  Is it the whole deck, or just the player's hand?  I assume you really want `playercard1 = randint(0,12)` and `if playercard1 in (10,11,12):`, but without seeing the rest of your design it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Lauren,
When you assign a value to the "playercard1" variable you use the "randint()" function. This function's parameters are two integers (a,b) such that the value returned from the "randint(") function is between a and b, including a and b themselves. The values you pass to this function are "cards[0]" and "cards[12]". I'm not sure what those values are, but I believe you meant to pass just the integers 0 and 12, like this.

```
playercard1 = randint(0,12)
```

Comment: Have a look at the question again - it may have been updated since your initial post. I believe the poster has what you are asking for and the problem is likely more around the list[index] than it is for the randint() call.

Answer (score 0):

when python interpreter raises that error message means that you are trying to acces and index that not exist in the array. Remember that the index arrays in python starts at 0 it means that if you have a list

```
aList = ['a','b','c','d']
```

the index will be: `[0,1,2,3]` . If you call

```
aList[3] #will return 'd'
```

but if you call for example:

```
aList[4] # will raise that error
```

This is a common error, maybe you are trying to access to list in a for loop, and you are not using the index correctly!

try to see where the error occurs and check what is happening with the index that you are using

Comment: How does this possibly help him?

Comment: Or her @TimRoberts

Comment: @TimRoberts he(she)'s having a problem with the index that is accesing, and does not know what the problem is, i'm trying to explain the problem and why is occurring with the information that he(she) proportioned.

Comment: You provided a totally generic description of an "index out of range" error.  From the description, I think it's clear they knew that.  A proper answer would point out why this specific chunk of code got this exception.  That's why we have people post code.  "try to see where the error occurs" is a useless suggestion.  That's why they posted the question.

Comment: @TimRoberts okey, I will try to sugest a better solution, sorry if wans clarifying. as he/she sayd: 'The output says that my list index is out of range, why is that?' 
I thought that this could help. Do you recomend me to erase the anwer?